# Is there a way to load and clip an image with a round border in P5.js?

Tags: canvas, p5.js

Loading and clipping an image can be done in fabricJS and with native Canvas methods but in P5.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one-line way to draw a rounded border is to call the [`rect()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rect) function with parameters that specify the corner radius. You might be able to draw that on top of an image to achieve the effect you're looking for.

If not, then the next best thing is to use the [`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) function to create a buffer. Draw your image to that buffer, then take the corners away from the buffer. Then you can draw the buffer to your canvas using the [`image()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image) function, exactly like you draw a regular image  to the canvas.

Another option is add the corners to your image ahead of time using an image editor.

Comment: Seems this is the best option for P5.js. Curious why such a workaround is necessary for P5?

Comment: @bresson It's not really a workaround, as this isn't a bug. The creators of Processing just decided to focus on other features instead of rounded corners on images (especially since you can already do it yourself if you want). P5.js is based on Processing, so they implement the same set of features. Luckily Processing is open source, so you could always add this feature yourself and make a pull request!

Answer (score 0):

In P5.js, if you wanna apply styles to image, the best solution is playing with p5 DOM Api.
with `[createImage()][1];`, you can play with the styles for animate things. here are some examples:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style

method:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createImg