# How to fill shapes with image in p5.js and matter.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I'm trying to work with p5.js and matter.js

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
            World = Matter.World,
            Body = Matter.Body,
            Events = Matter.Events,
            Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
        var engine;
        var world;
        var box1;
        var boxes = [];

        var ground;

        var img;

        function setup() {
            createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            engine = Engine.create();
            world = engine.world;
            Engine.run(engine);
            ground = new Boundary(window.innerWidth /2, window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth, 10);
            World.add(world, ground);
            img = loadImage("https://i.ibb.co/jZccXfR/image.png");
        }

            

        function mouseDragged() {
            boxes.push(new Ball(mouseX, mouseY, 20))
        }
        function mousePressed() {
            boxes.push(new Ball(mouseX, mouseY, 20))
        }

        function draw() {
            background(51);

            for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
                boxes[i].show();
                img.mask(boxes[i]);
            }
            ground.show();
        }
```

This is the code I wrote. ( without mask function in draw, it works fine)
when i run this code, error "srcImage.loadPixels is not a function" is occured.
How can i fill shapes with image?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to move the image loading to `preload()` first (see [loadImage() reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) for more details):

```
function preload(){
   img = loadImage("https://i.ibb.co/jZccXfR/image.png");
}
```

it's unclear what `boxes[i]` are, but hopefully they are [p5.Image](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) (or [p5.Graphics](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Graphics)) instances, otherwise you won't be able to use them as masks.

Currently it looks like you're applying masks to the same image: each `mask()` call will override the previous so it's only the last box that will be used as a mask. alternatively you can use a p5.Graphics instance to draw white boxes on a black background using boxes[i] x, y, w, h properties.

Once `img` is loaded you can make a copy which you can reuse if you want to "reset" back to the original if applying masks to the raw image multiple times eventually erode the image completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't complete, but here's one you can hopefully adapt to your use case:

```js
function drawShape(body, color=225) {
  beginShape();
  fill(color);
  body.vertices.forEach(({x, y}) => vertex(x,  y));
  endShape();
}

const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const box = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(150, 0, 40, 40);
const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  200, 200, 400, 120, {isStatic: true}
);
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
Matter.Composite.add(
  engine.world, [box, ground, mouseConstraint]
);
let img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("https://picsum.photos/40/40");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 300);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  clear();

  const {x, y} = box.position;
  push();
  translate(x, y);
  rotate(box.angle);
  image(img, -20, -20);
  pop();

  // drawShape(box, "red");
  drawShape(ground, "black");
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

For circular images, see [Is there a way to load and clip an image with a round border in P5.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126139/is-there-a-way-to-load-and-clip-an-image-with-a-round-border-in-p5-js/39126607#39126607), but you can also do the shape clipping beforehand. I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure arbitrarily-shaped polygons (like most sprites with jagged edges) can be loaded and drawn as rectangle images with transparency, each backed with a [vertices](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Bodies.html#method_fromVertices)-based Matter body.